# Convert base64 to buffer in node is different from fs.readFile buffer

Tags: node.js, axios, base64, buffer

I am building a proxy that needs to accept a base64 encoded image and pass it as raw bites to another API (that I don't control) using Axios and form-data.

The issue is that if I pass base64 using Axios the call fails to generate a file on the API.

However, if I pass a buffer:

```
Buffer.from(base64FromRequest)
```

it generates a file but it is corrupted.

I tested by using a local file:

```
const testFile= fs.readFileSync(*);
```

and passing the output to the API and it works.
But if I get the testFile and convert it to a base64 buffer and then back to buffer it creates a corrupted file.

```
const base64FromTestFile = Buffer.from(localFile).toString('base64');
const bufferFromFile = Buffer.from(base64FromTestFile);
```

I can see that the buffer array for localFile is shorter than the buffer array from bufferFromFile .

Any idea on what may be the issue?

My code:

```
    // Test with local file
    const testFile = fs.readFileSync('/iconQA.png');
    //Convert testFile to base64 buffer
    const base64FromTestFile = Buffer.from(testFile).toString('base64');
    
    // Base64 from request
    const base64FromRequest = request['filecontent']['content'];

    // True
    console.log(base64FromTestFile === base64FromRequest);

    const bufferFromFile = Buffer.from(base64FromTestFile);
    const bufferRequest = Buffer.from(base64FromRequest);

    //Works
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('f', 'json');
    params.append('token', token);
    params.append('attachment', testFile, 'testFile.png');
    
    //Corrupted file
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('f', 'json');
    params.append('token', token);
    params.append('attachment', bufferFromFile, 'bufferFromFile.png');
    
    //Corrupted file
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('f', 'json');
    params.append('token', token);
    params.append('attachment', bufferRequest, 'bufferRequest.png');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the encoding argument `Buffer.from(base64FromTestFile, 'base64')`